# Shorten the path of area in asp.net core 5 Razor pages

Tags: asp.net-core, routes, razor-pages

How can i conver routing of "Identity/Account" to "/Account" for all pages?

Answer (score 1):

In your startup.cs you can change :

```
services.AddRazorPages();
```

with :

```
services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
            options.Conventions.AddAreaFolderRouteModelConvention("Identity", "/Account/", model =>
            {
                foreach (var selector in model.Selectors)
                {
                    var attributeRouteModel = selector.AttributeRouteModel;
                    attributeRouteModel.Order = -1;
                    attributeRouteModel.Template = attributeRouteModel.Template.Remove(0, "Identity".Length);
                }
            })
        );
```